# Puppeteer file form issue

Tags: forms, file, automation, puppeteer

Hi I can't accede to the input field. I have tried with id, class, name, title inserting a delay but without success.

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

//const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const preparePageForTests = async (page) => {

    // Pass the User-Agent Test.
    const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)' +
      'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.39 Safari/537.36';
    await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
    }

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await preparePageForTests(page);
  

  await page.goto('https://serviciosenlinea.bps.gub.uy/ServiciosEnLineaWeb/contenidosEmbebido?id=8782', {
    waitUntil: "networkidle0", //domcontentloaded networkidle0
  });




  await page.screenshot({
    path: 'images/skjdkjkfj.jpg'
  });

 
 
  await page.waitForSelector('[title=empresa]');
  await page.typte('[title=empresa]', 'ssddsd');
  

  await page.waitForSelector('#frmBasico:txtEmpresat');
  await page.typte('#frmBasico:txtEmpresat', 'ssddsd');

  
  await page.screenshot({
    path: 'images/screenshot11.jpg'
  });

 await page.waitForSelector('.inputAlfanumerico');
 await page.waitForSelector('#frmBasico:txtEmpresat');
 await page.type('.inputAlfanumerico', 'Noseeee');
 await page.type('#frmBasico:txtEmpresat', 'Noseeee');
 await page.screenshot({
    path: 'images/screenshot.jpg'
  });

  await page.focus('.frmBasico:txtDocumento');
  await page.keyboard.type('342323243');


  
  
  //await browser.close();
})();
```

I have tried with id, class, name, title inserting a delay but without success. I can't auto complete the inputs.

Any one know how to auto complete the inputs and submit in this case??

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I got this error at the first step by manually.
`Errores encontrados Número de documento: No es un valor válido`
Do you have any documentation # information for passing first step?

Comment: Hi, the error is because the introduced information are official document numbers from persons and the vat number from their own businesses. I don't have any test data. But is not necessary my propose is to target the filds to fill automatically and submit for the next page. After this, every person will fill the data in the program, and it will generate the invoice every month automatically for them. So they will never forget again and avoid fines.